# OpenMDAO Internal recorder efficiency low?

Tags: python, openmdao

I was recently ''forced'' to use gradient free optimizers (including the ones in pyoptsparse)

Before, the number of iterations were considerably low so recording the data was never a big problem and i was opting for the internal recorder.

But for an optimization problem with more than say 30.000 iterations reading the in data from the case-recorder becomes very cumbersome.

If I were to use a code to simply append to a txt file in every iteration it is much quicker to read in and plot. I would like to ask if i am making a mistake or is it really better to use ''append binary txt file''.

The steps:

optimization problem of 1 des var, 1 constraint, 1 objective ~ 60000 iterations sql file size ~ 30 MB

```
cr = CaseReader(fname)
case_keys = cr.driver_cases.list_cases()
ab=[cr.driver_cases.get_case(case_key).get_objectives()['a.obj'][0] for case_key in case_keys ]
```

time spent : i stopped after 10 minutes still reading....

```
f=open('out.dat','ab')
np.savetxt(f,[desvar,constraint,objec])
f.close() np.loadtxt( 'out.dat')
```

time spent: within seconds....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/commit/d0f073dfde3508e645775151a24a02717f61679e) commit we were able to make the CaseReader much more efficient for the case you've described. The `iteration_coordinate` column in the system, driver, and solver iteration tables is now indexed, which should significantly decrease the time required to get a case through the `get_case` method for large databases. We've also added a `load_cases` method to the *CaseReader* that loads all cases into memory with minimal queries, further improving the efficiency of the `get_case` method.

Grabbing the most recent version of OpenMDAO and updating your code to use `load_cases` should help quite a bit.

```
    cr = CaseReader(fname)
    cr.load_cases()
    case_keys = cr.driver_cases.list_cases()
    ab=[cr.driver_cases.get_case(case_key).get_objectives()['a.obj'][0] for case_key in case_keys ]
```

You can find documentation for this in the **Loading a DataBase Into Memory** section here: http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/getting_values.html